# How to set RMQ vhost max connections

Tags: rabbitmq

currently my vhost max-connection limit is set to 15,000. I'm looking to override that default. I found some documentation to override the limit on a per vhost basis but I would like to override the main default one.

https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.12.4/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html

`curl -4u 'guest:guest' -H 'content-type:application/json' -X PUT localhost:15672/api/user-limits/guest/max-connections -d '{"value": 50}'`

I tried setting guest to vhost, that didn't work either.